# What's the difference between a "nook" and a "cranny"?

Tags: meaning

I think both words mean a sort of crevice or corner. Presumably there must be some significant difference.

The words are almost always used together:

e.g.

> She searched in every **nook and cranny**

Presumably they can be used separately. I think I may have heard "nook" on its own, but never "cranny".

Interestingly the N-gram seems to suggest "nook" is more commonly used than "cranny".

[image]

Comment: Many U.S. readers over 40, upon hearing the term "nooks & crannies," will immediately be reminded of an old tagline for Thomas' English muffins: _with lots of nooks and crannies to hold the melted butter_. Until today, I thought that phrase was mere adspeak; I didn't realize it was a [closely guarded trade secret](http://www.usatoday.com/money/industries/food/2010-07-29-english-muffin-lawsuit_N.htm).

Comment: It reminds me of the line: "_Oh, I love every part of you, every nook and cranny. Oh, **especially** your cranny_". I believe it's from "_third rock from the sun_".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the OED’s definitions, *nook* seems to have the meaning of some kind of corner, whereas a *cranny* is some kind of opening or crack. Together they cover a range of possible places in which a thorough search might be conducted. I think either on its own would be rare in current English.

Comment: "Nook" survives by itself in phrases like "breakfast nook".  I wouldn't have breakfast in a cranny.

Comment: From which we get the spoonerism, [“crooks and nannies”](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crook_and_nanny).

Comment: “Nook” survives also as the market name for an ebook device. Can it be said that this meaning is being used?

Comment: I guess a "breakfast cranny" is like a "breakfast nook" only much smaller...

Comment: You get *nooks* in gardens, too. I can't think of a use for *cranny* without *nook* though.

Answer (score 4):

1)A "nook" is a corner or a small, partially enclosed area of a larger room. A "cranny" is a crack or a crevice.

2)A nook is a sheltered and secluded place.

3)A nook is a recess esp. one offering seclusion or security.
A cranny is a small narrow space or opening.

4)A nook is a small corner of a house, or a secluded spot.
A cranny is a crack or hole in something

5)A nooks are high, crannys are low.
A cranny is a a long narrow depression in a surface.

6)A nook is in.
A cranny is out.

The phrase 'every little nook and cranny' means every part or aspect of something.

Comment: Now that I've read #6, I might try using this terminology when discussing bellybuttons, as in: "What about your navel?  Do you have a _nook_ or a _cranny_?"

Comment: That's not quite what "every little nook and cranny" means. It's referring to *spaces* (along the same lines as your 1-6).